# How can I navigate JSON nested file using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Thank you for help in advance . here is my problem , I'm finding trouble to explore a json nested file and try . Here is my json file

```
 {"Id":466,"Name":"korea",
"Occurrences":                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [
   {"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1398207600000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":27},
   {"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1398726000000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":1},
   {"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1398898800000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":4},
   {"OccurrenceDate":"\/Date(1399071600000+0100)\/","OccurrenceFrequency":303}]}
```

This is my code Javascript code:

```
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 <script>



 d3.json("data2.json", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {

    console.log(d.Id)
    console.log(d.Name)
    console.log(d.Occurrence.OccurrenceFrequency)
    console.log(d.Occurrence.OccurrenceDate)})

    return d;
  });
}); 
</script>
```

Really looking for a help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. Given your format, which is an object, you can't use forEach on it, but it doesn't appear that you need to.

```
d3.json("data2.json", function(error, data) {
  console.log(data.Id)
  console.log(data.Name)
  data.Occurences.forEach(function(d) {

    console.log(d.OccurrenceFrequency)
    console.log(d.OccurrenceDate)})

    return d;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Kalley but this code only type the Id and and Name. But it doesn't log OccurrenceFrequency and OccurrenceDate. It showed this error : TypeError: d3.each is not a function

Comment: @user3608559 yeah, I had typed something over that was incorrect. I fixed the bug.

Comment: still the same .It only type 466 and korea which are the data.id and data.name , respectively .. and this is what is the console types as an error   **TypeError: data.forEach is not a function**                                                           **Domain is: null**